# Redirect by user role from a specific admin url to another url

Tags: php, wordpress, function, redirect, roles

This code works fine if I use *is_front_page* as current page/url, because it gets my homepage and redirects user by role to a specific path, but it doesn't work if I try to get a specific current url of wp admin dashboard, I tried with *get_home_url(path)*, but it doesn't work:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'role_based_redirect' );
function role_based_redirect() {
    if( get_home_url('/wp-admin/current-url') !== false ) { // this doesn't work
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url( '/wp-admin/other-url' ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

template_redirect hook is for front-side of your website. For admin side you can use different hooks. Such as init, admin_init etc.

f.e.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'role_based_redirect' );
function role_based_redirect() {
    if( strpos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'wp-admin/current-url') !== false ) { 
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url( '/wp-admin/other-url' ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you I used '/wp-admin/current-url' with the slash before current url